# Why is saving a picture twice in a row producing different binary in Paint

Tags: image, binary, png, paint, binaryfiles

I thought this was a little odd.
Open Paint on Windows (I'm using Windows 7) and draw something (anything).
Then save as a .png for example called 1.png. Then save 'n' number of other copies straight away without modifying the image (2.png, 3.png,..etc).

I notice that 1.png has a different checksum to 2/3/4/../n.png.
1.png also varies in such (sometimes smaller and other times bigger) compared to the other images.

What is going on?

Comment: Reddit discussion: http://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/319qbw/why_is_saving_a_picture_twice_in_a_row_producing/

Comment: Can you insert two "same" png's in this post? There is a number of checks one may run on them.

Comment: @Jongware Sure here you go: http://imgur.com/a/nYxRl

The top image is 1.png and the bottom is 2.png. Imgur hasn't modified the images in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in filesize is due to the choice of scanline filters used by the compressor.  I don't have any idea why your application would use a different set of filters when compressing the image multiple times, but it's harmless.

There's no time stamp in the two images that Mohammad posted.  According to "pngcheck -v", the only difference is in the content of the IDAT chunk.  The image signatures computed by ImageMagick are identical.  Neither image contains a tIME chunk.

"pngcrush" produces two identical images with a smaller filesize (11493 bytes).

According to "pngtest -mv" (pngtest is included in the libpng distribution), one image uses only the PNG "none" filter while the other uses the "none", "sub", and "up" filters.

Comment: Yes this seems to be correct. I'm still curious as to why Paint does this but there is no easy way to find out.

Answer (score 0):

The Wikipedia article on the PNG format seems to suggest there's a timestamp in there. That alone would do it.

Doesn't explain why subsequent files have the same checksum.

Comment: Also happens with other formats like jpg. Headers are the same but the 1st image is different from the 2nd but the 2nd-10th (I did 9 in a row) were exactly the same.

I used diff checker to compare the binary and there seems to be random small changes in the data itself.

Comment: The PNG format itself does not carry a timestamp. It may be added in an optional `tIME` chunk, but that has a fixed format and size, so it would not influence the file size.